# Node js request module, how to use data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, request, token

I am using the code below to retrieve a refresh_token. When I run it, I get the token in the console but if I want to return something instead, I get nothing. Basically I cannot use this code to generate a token that can then be use in another piece of code. What am I missing?

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  form: {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    refresh_token: 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: above code, your console displayed token ?

Comment: Yes, the console displays the token if i do console.log(body). But i want to instead get that token, and use it somewhere else. I am not sure how.

Comment: i got it, do you know asynchronous ?

Comment: A bit, i am still new to this.

Comment: ok, i'll help you

Comment: Look at [the documentation for request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). It is deprecated. You shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: @Quentin I saw, but i can't find any other method that works for that specific api. Do you have any suggestion that would be equivalent to the above post?

Comment: You can make a request like that with any of the common libraries for making HTTP requests.

Comment: i resolved my issue with the following code:

`async function getAccessToken() {
    const fs = require("fs");
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2);
    const axios = require("axios");
    const oauth = require("axios-oauth-client");
    const getRefreshToken = oauth.client(axios.create(), {
        url: "URL",
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        client_id: "ID",
        client_secret: "secret",
        refresh_token:
            "token",
        scope:
            "scope",
    });

    const auth = await getRefreshToken();`